# Make database class

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following class:

```
public class Database  {
    private Connection connection;
    private MyApp instance = MyApp.getInstance();
    private String database, host, username, password, port;
    private Config config = new Config();

    public Connection Database() {
        database = config.get("database.database");
        host = config.get("database.host");
        username = config.get("database.username");
        password = config.get("database.password");
        port = config.get("database.port");
        try {
            connection = openConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private Connection openConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {

        }

        synchronized (instance) {
            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {

            }
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

I'd like to be able to return connection on this class so I can, in other classes, do `connection = new Database()`. and then `Statement statement = connection.createStatement();`.

This probably and feels like this isn't the best way, and I'm not sure what is a better way of creating a database class. My attempt was trying to do `return connection;` in the constructor but that error'd out.

How do I do this?

Comment: Its looks like you want to write a class which acts like a ConnectionPool?

Comment: This is generally not recommended because then you have no way of accessing the database object. If the database class/instance is really just there to build a connection, you could use a static factory method e.g. `connection = Database.createConnection()`

Comment: Don't write your own implementation of ConnectionPool, just use https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP or https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Answer (score 1):

**You can try something like this :**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Baza {

private static java.sql.Connection conect = null;
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Application?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
private static final String username = "root";
private static final String password = "";
private final String urlWithoutBase= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

public Baza() {
    try {
        conect = DriverManager.getConnection(urlWithoutBase, username, password);
        createDataBase();
        conect.close();
        openConnection();
        createTablePeople();
        conect.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }    
}

public Connection openConnection() {
    try {
        conect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conect;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conect;
}

public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        conect.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private void createDataBase() throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = conect.createStatement();
    String query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Application;";
    statement.execute(query);
}
 private void createTablePeople() throws SQLException{
      Statement statement = conect.createStatement();
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Osobe("
            + "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            + "name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,"
            + "surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,"
            + "date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,"               
            + "PRIMARY KEY(id));";
    statement.execute(query);
 }
```

}